# Debugging permission denied in Cloud Firestore SDK (Golang)

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I am experienced in working with AWS but this is my first foray onto Google cloud and I am stuck on how to debug it properly.  I am building a simple experimental setup, using Cloud Firestore to store some data and planning to do some small API functions to query it.

I am inputting my information from a Go app, which I built using the official SDK for Go.  Everything builds fine, but when I run it I see nothing other than `rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.`.

I have tried setting the authentication to open in the Firestore rules console (`allow read, write: if true`), but I *still* see the same error, so it seems to be an issue with the credentials I have generated rather than Firestore itself.

The credentials in question were generated in the main Google Cloud Console, under Service Accounts.  I've saved it out as a JSON file and am loading this into the app via `option.WithCredentialsFile()` which is then passed into the `NewFirestoreWriter()` constructor.

It's far from obvious, to me at least, exactly how to configure the permissions on the Service Account as it seems to work quite differently from Amazon IAM.  I was expecting to find a way to add on specific actions related to Firestore but I can't find anything at all like that once the service account is created.  Under Permissions, it looks like I can associate other accounts with the service account, which seems to be the other way around to what I want to do.  Or do I need to assume another identity once I have the service account in order to do anything, a la Amazon STS?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

I am running locally while I am playing with the apps, planning to think about deployment later.

I guess my questions are:

- Should I be using a different form of credential when making programmatic writes to Firestore?
- What permissions need to be on the credential that I am using?
- How do the Google Service Account permissions interact with the Firestore access rules, or are they completely separate?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to go trough Firebase quickstart for Go? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#go_1

Comment: yep that's pretty much what i'm doing - initialise the service account, download the json credentials and then feed it into the constructor via `options...`

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked out the answer. Turns out I was reading some of the screens too fast....

The programmatic approach with the credential was fine, but the service account setup was not.

In case anyone else has a similar issue, the fix was to:

- Go to "Access" under IAM (NOT identity). Coming from AWS this confused me a little because I was expecting roles to be a sublevel to identity rather than a seperate level
- Click the Edit button next to the service account
- Add the Cloud Datastore User and Cloud Datastore Owner roles (I'll work on trimming down permissions now it's working!).  This confused me particularly because I was looking for "Firestore" or "Cloud Firestore", and there is the very similarly named "Cloud Filestore" which tripped me up.

After a few seconds, it started working.

According to https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/libraries?_ga=2.87049368.-1865513281.1592929406#server_client_libraries,

> In this environment, requests are not evaluated against your Firestore security rules

So I reset my access permissions in Firebase back to `allow read, write: if false`.